# Fastest way to convert SVG to EMF repeatably using Inkscape and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, inkscape

Python 3.9.0
Inkscape 0.92

I use Inkscape to convert SVG to EMF, however it takes too much time.

**Simple example code**

```
import subprocess

def convert_svg_to_emf(input_svg_path, output_emf_path):
    # This method takes ~1 seconds
    subprocess.run([
        "C:\\Inkscape\\Inkscape.exe", # Inkscape executor path
        input_svg_path, # Input SVG file
        "--export-emf",
        output_emf_path # Output EMF file
    ])

# Assume I have 100 files to convert
for i in range(100):
    convert_svg_to_emf(f"svg{i}.svg", f"emf{i}.emf")

# This script takes ~100 seconds
```

Although it depends on input files, but every single call of '***convert_svg_to_emf***' takes at least few seconds. But when I try converting it from Inkscape directly, a output file appears almost immediately. So I presume 'opening' and 'quitting' of the application by ***subprocess.run*** charges most processing time.

Is there any method to make this faster?

**My expectation**

```
inkscape = open_inkscape() # Keep opening Inkscape app

for i in range(100):
    inkscape.convert_svg_to_emf(f"svg{i}.svg", f"emf{i}.emf")

inkscape.quit() # Quit the app after all work done

# This script conducts 'opening' and 'quitting' just once regardless of number of files.
```

Answer (score 0):

Inkscape offers some [commandline options](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Using_the_Command_Line). The most efficient way is to use the pipe command, or to run Inkscape in Shell Mode. From the examples:

```
cat my_file.svg | inkscape --pipe --export-filename=my_file.pdf
```